# why react using the term "node" with null,undefined,true and false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it is not clear to me when I read in react [doc (beta)](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createElement#parameters) that :

**null, undefined, true and false** is empty `nodes` ?

I know this not going to render anything if I pass it as a children to react element which is empty but why to call it nodes any reasons?

Comment: I guess it is a list of react nodes: https://reactnative.dev/docs/react-node
It is probably just a fail-safe feature

Comment: the term "node" it not only used in react. it's a core principle of a (virtual) DOM in js